# Refactoring if-elseif block to hash and classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns, refactoring

I'm working on the legacy asp.net code (however it was converted to newest .net version), I encountered file which contains 15 500 long if-elseif block (with 700 conditions). Each condition is of the same structure:

```
if(a == "aaa")
{
  .....
}
else if(a == "bbb")
{
 ....
}
.....
```

I think it needs to be refactored. I want to split the code from each block into separe classes, name them as "aaa", "bbb", ... and use Dictionary or Hashtable to store references to them. It would probably have an Interface with method execute() with the certain return type. The problem is that I think instantiation of each class and storing the objects to hash table would take some time and I believe that performancewise it would be worse thing (for each request constructing hashtable). It would have to store total of 700 objects and then it would retrieve only one object. My questions are:

1. Is there any better way of solving such a problem? For example, maybe I shall store classes instead of objects, and then use reflection to instantiate class and call its method?
2. How painful it would be performance wise to apply such design (dividing if/else if blocks into classes -> add objects (which implement certain interface) to dictionary --> take one object from dictionary
3. Let's say I put all the classes to folder F, how could I retrieve all the classes and add them to dictionary
4. Any suggestions, other ways to solve the problem?

Comment: _I believe that performancewise it would be worse thing (for each request constructing hashtable)_ - I really don't think it would take any noticeable time to create, but noting that if your hash table is held in a static variable, it only instantiates once.

Comment: Your performance question can be answered by you *making a small example of the pattern you intend to attempt*, and *running the code to see how fast it is*. We can't make a prediction about how code that you haven't written will perform in the future! If you want to know how fast a thing is, build it and then measure its speed.

Comment: What if you use a `HashSet<string, Action<>>` and intialize with lambdas for each possible key? Also note that if you use a `switch`, the [compiler will build a jump table for you](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/322788/274834) and use that, though that still involves (integer) hash comparisons and a string comparison to verify.

Comment: Note though depending on the spread (and number) of `case` values, the compiler may be do a binary search instead of a hash table lookup.

Comment: @stuard Would it be a better idea to search classes that implement certain interface and then automatically instantiating objects of these classes, adding them to hash table. Or it would be better to write 700 cases for each class? I assume reflection is not a good practice, but I would save lots of lines.

Comment: @NetMage I did not mention in the post, but each if/else if block sets parameters for T-SQL stored procedures. We want to convert T-SQL to C# using EF and I assume dividing these cases to classes would be a better idea. We could build business logic around these classes.The caller of this huge if/elseif method gets SQL command with standard parameters set and then it adds additional parameters that are specified by user and executes command.

Comment: Therefore, afterwards I would refactor each T-SQL stored procedure to C# logic, gradually this manager class would be obsolete as each call would be made directly to these 700 classes. This is just a context for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't need instance variables, I would recommend a static class with each of these as a separate function.  Then you can define a compatible delegate method, and store references to the functions themselves rather than the classes.  Since they'd be executed in a static context, there would be no need for class instantiation.

It would require a bit of memory to load up the hash map, but after that the footprint would be negligible.

Comment: Hence my suggestion to use lambdas - the compiler will create the classes and handle references for you.